# Add comma after each word

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have a variable (called $document_keywords) with following text in it:

```
Latex document starter CrypoServer
```

I want to add comma after each word, not after last word. So, output will become like this:

```
Latex, document, starter, CrypoServer
```

Anybody help me to achieve above output.

regards,
Ankit

Comment: Kindly post your attempts to solve the problem when asking a question

Answer (score 5):

In order to preserve whitespaces as they are given, I would use sed like this:

```
echo "$document_keywords" | sed 's/\>/,/g;s/,$//'
```

This works as follows:

```
s/\>/,/g   # replace all ending word boundaries with a comma -- that is,
           # append a comma to every word
s/,$//     # then remove the last, unwanted one at the end.
```

Then:

```
$ echo 'Latex document starter CrypoServer' | sed 's/\>/,/g;s/,$//'
Latex, document, starter, CrypoServer
$ echo 'Latex   document starter CrypoServer' | sed 's/\>/,/g;s/,$//'
Latex,   document, starter, CrypoServer
```

Comment: thanks for your help.

how to skip "()" in below text?
before
Latex document starter Safe(R) CrypoServer

after
Latex, document, starter, Safe(R) CrypoServer

Comment: Kind of depends on where exactly you want to skip commas. For this particular case, you could use `sed 's/\([^[:space:])]\)\([[:space:]]\)/\1,\2/g'` or, if you know there are no tabs or similar, `sed 's/\([^ )]\) /\1, /g'`. For a general answer, I'd have to know by what precise rules your input is constructed and should be processed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `awk` for this purpose. Loop using `for` and add a `,` after any char except on the last occurance (when i == NF).

```
$ echo $document_keywords | awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)if(i!=NF){$i=$i","}  }1'
```

Answer (score 4):

A normal sed gave me the expected output,

```
sed 's/ /, /g' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

Using BASH string substitution:

```
document_keywords='Latex document starter CrypoServer'
echo "${document_keywords//[[:blank:]]/,}"
Latex,document,starter,CrypoServer
```

Or `sed`:

```
echo "$document_keywords" | sed 's/[[:blank:]]/,/g'
Latex,document,starter,CrypoServer
```

Or `tr`:

```
echo "$document_keywords" | tr '[[:blank:]]/' ','
Latex,document,starter,CrypoServer
```